# Mobile rendering won't stretch 100%

Tags: html, css

Hello on my site I have a header/footer wrapper that goes 100% width, this has a different bg image on it to the rest, however when i go to the site on a mobile it only stretches 90% of the width, i'm in the process of converting the site to a responsive grid system I recently developed so the current version will only be live for a few more weeks however it's something i would rather fix anyone know whats up??
URL: [jp creative vision](http://jpcreativevision.co.uk/)
CSS for the header

```
#header{
padding: 0;
height:60px;
width:100%;
background-image:url(../images/general/background_top.jpg);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 5px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 5px #000000;
}
    #nav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top:0;
        width:1000px;
    }
        #nav ul{
            float:right;
        }
        #nav li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #nav li a, #nav li a:visited {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            display: block;
            padding: .31em .60em;
            transition: border 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: border 1s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: border 1s ease-in-out;
        }
        #nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active, #nav li a:focus {
            border-bottom: solid 10px #336699;

        }
        #nav ul:last-child{
            margin-right:0px;
            padding-right:0px;
        }
```

Anyone know what my issue is? Thanks for the help :)

Edit, the problem is the wrapper in header and footer that should stretch 100% only do 90% on mobiles.

Comment: your question is very unclear, please rephrase...

Comment: I too am confused by the question. When i go on your site on mobile the backrground images dont appear at all?

Answer (score 0):

First of all do a

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

in your style sheet. 
 Then this is the style you have with media queries with min width 900px

```
media="screen and (min-width: 900px)"
```

try handling smaller widths.

and also doing a `width:100%` for the body in  global style. Then carry on with media styles. You can see the effect when you resize your browser also :) try test lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggeling with this question too much. Use this meta code to stop mobile devices from zooming out. Hope this helps.

```
<meta content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
```

I've been looking through your site btw, it is really too much text to give a visitor a message quick. Use more images, so users have to do as less as possible.